# Ionic application works on browser but not on phone

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I am using AngularJS to create pop-up boxes under a description.
I have two pages; on the first page, everything works perfectly.
On the second page, on mobile devices, the boxes are not triggered when clicking on words. But it works on a desktop browser.
I know the problem is in my CSS (as usual) but I cannot seem to find it.

My current code is like this:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="contenu" >


        <div class="box1">
          <a href="#" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed"  style="color:#259B24"> MyRhoom </a>
          <div class="bordered" ng-show="collapsed" style="position: fixed; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000; background-color: #FBC02D; " >I am description</div>
        </div>

        <div class="box2">
          <a href="#" ng-model="collapsed2" ng-click="collapsed2=!collapsed2"  style="color:#FBC02D"> Talent </a>
          <div class="bordered" ng-show="collapsed2" >I am description</div>
        </div>


    <div  align="center">
        <img src="img/Image2.jpg" class="im">
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="box3">
          <a href="#" ng-model="collapsed3" ng-click="collapsed3=!collapsed3"  style="color:#FBC02D"> WTR </a>
          <div class="bordered" ng-show="collapsed3" >I am description</div>
        </div>
    </div>



      <div class="box4">
        <a href="#" ng-model="collapsed4" ng-click="collapsed4=!collapsed4"  style="color:#F44336"> Skype </a>
        <div class="bordered" ng-show="collapsed4">I am description</div>
      </div>

      <div class="box5">
        <a href="#" ng-model="collapsed5" ng-click="collapsed5=!collapsed5"  style="color:#259B24"> Ulysse </a>
        <div class="bordered" ng-show="collapsed5">I am description</div>
      </div>

      <div class="box6">
        <a href="#" ng-model="collapsed6" ng-click="collapsed6=!collapsed6"  style="color:#F44336"> Egencia </a>
        <div class="bordered" ng-show="collapsed6" >I am description</div>
      </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box1 {

position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
left: 3%;
top: 70%;
font-size: 14pt;

}
.box2 {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
left:72%;
top: 60%;
font-size: 14pt;

}

.box3 {

position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
left: 5%;
top: 80%;
font-size: 14pt;

}

.box4 {

position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
left: 5%;
top: 60%;
font-size: 14pt;

}
.box5{

position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
left: 72%;
top: 70%;
font-size: 14pt;

}

.box6 {

position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
left: 72%;
top: 80%;
font-size: 14pt;

}
.contenu .bordered {
position: fixed;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000;
  background-color: #FBC02D; 

}
```

Giving me this:

[image: picture 1]

When I change `.box1, .box2`, etc to `.contenu.box1`, I get it to work but the layout is not maintained.

[image: picture 2]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're changing the position property and the layout changes. Why is this surprising? Also, code formatting and DRY structure are your friends. You have a lot of random indentation and repetition up there.

Comment: can you help me with that? I am new to all this :/

Comment: besides, it is working on the browser. what is the difference :/

Comment: I have no understanding of what you're trying to accomplish by changing position from absolute to relative on some elements. The specific problem isn't clear.

Comment: I want the same layout as the first picture but when i click it does not show the pop up box (ng-model)